# Projection of subfields by key name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose model defined as

```
var VillageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {en: String, de: String, it: String},
  shortDescription: {en: String, de: String, it: String},
  longDescription: {en: String, de: String, it: String},
  publicTransport: Boolean,
  pictures: [String],
  coordinates: { lat: Number, lng: Number },  
  mainAttractions: [{
    name: { en: String, de: String, it: String },
    description: { en: String, de: String, it: String },
    pictures: [String]
  }],
  culinarySpecialities: [{
    name: { en: String, de: String, it: String },
    description: { en: String, de: String, it: String },
    pictures: [String]
  }]
})
```

As you some fields and collection contain localized content (en/de/it for english/german/italian) and some don't. 
What I would like to achieve is filtering out all the localized content except for one language (depending on user language), so if the user is german I only want to return `"de"` values.

I can write a projection like:

```
{ "name.de": 1, publicTransport: 1, "shortDescription.de": 1, ... }
```

but I was wondering if there's a better way to return all language-independent fields, something like `{'*.en': 1 }`

Comment: You really cannot do that. You are better of doing something along the lines of `"language": "en", "text": "english text"` in some arrangement or another. MongoDB like most databases is concerned with "values" rather than names of keys when searching. There are ways ( in some of the linked responses ) but they all basically involve scanning the collection in order to "coerce" the names of keys into values so they can be tested. Not efficient. Favor fixed named attributes with "variable data" over named keys.

Comment: True but in my case is not about searching (search is by `_id`) is about dynamically projecting fields and subfields.

Comment: Same deal. You "cannot traverse keys" by an unknown name, for exactly the same reasons. You really should make those "values". Then you can very easily `$filter` for the matching values and even "default" where needed. Point is "don't think **key** think **value**. Plenty of resources on "filtering an array".

Comment: Got your point!, thanks